# Erro "Notice: Undefined index: matricula"

Tags: php

Tenho dois códigos idênticos. Um funciona (user) e outro não(carros). Alguém me sabe explicar pq?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Codigo para os carros:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Eliminar</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    include("validar.php");
    include("ligaBD.php");

    $procura = "SELECT * FROM carros WHERE matricula LIKE '%".$_GET["mat"]."%'";
    $faz_procura = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $procura);
    $num_registos = mysqli_num_rows($faz_procura);

    if($num_registos==0)
    {
        echo "Não foram encontrados registos. ";
        echo "<a href='edita_elimina_carro.html'>Faça nova pesquisa";
        exit;
    }else
    {
        echo "<table border=0 width=300px><tr bgcolor=red>";
        echo "<th>Nome</th><th>Idade</th><th>Email</th><th>Username</th>";
        echo "<th>Password</th><th>Apagar</th></tr>";

        for($i=0; $i<$num_registos; $i++)
        {
            $registos = mysqli_fetch_array($faz_procura);
            if($i & 1)
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor=yellow>';
            }else
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor=grey>';
            }
            echo '<td>'.$registos['matricula'];
            echo '<td>'.$registos['user'];
            echo '<td>'.$registos['marca'];
            echo '<td>'.$registos['ano'];
            echo '<td>'.$registos['celindrada'];
            echo '<td><a href="apaga_carro.php?nome='.$registos['matricula'].'">Elimina</a>';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Outro:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Eliminar</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    include("validar_admin.php");
?>

<h3>Eliminar Utilizadores</h3>
<form method="GET" name="form1" action="edita_elimina_carronew.php">
<input type="text" name="mat">
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

ERROS:

> Notice: Undefined index: matricula in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Modulo 7 - Trabalho n5\edita_elimina_carronew.php on line 37

Este erro ocorre varias para todos os items no código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: provavelmente a tabela **carros** não tenha o atributo **matricula** da uma conferida

Comment: Ele da o mesmo erro para todos os atributos.. :/

Comment: posta a estrutura das duas tabelas, coloca só o código do arquivo edita_elimina_carronew.php os arquivos que não tem erro não precisa postar

Comment: Ja editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se utiliza a função `mysqli_fetch_array`, é gerado um array com os indices exatamente com o mesmo nome dos campos da sua tabela.

Por exemplo, a sua tabela `carros` possui o campo `Matricula`, logo a chave no array será `Matricula` e não `matricula` com letra minúscula.

O erro `Notice: Undefined index: matricula...` ocorre porque em PHP os indices de um array são case sensitive. É gerado um hash para cada indice, sendo assim um hash com letra "M" é diferente de um hash com a letra "m".

Faça essa correção no seu código:

```
    <?php
        include("validar.php");
        include("ligaBD.php");

        $procura = "SELECT * FROM carros WHERE matricula LIKE '%".$_GET["mat"]."%'";
        $faz_procura = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $procura);
        $num_registos = mysqli_num_rows($faz_procura);

        if($num_registos==0) {
            echo "Não foram encontrados registos. ";
            echo "<a href='edita_elimina_carro.html'>Faça nova pesquisa";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "<table border=0 width=300px><tr bgcolor=red>";
            echo "<th>Nome</th><th>Idade</th><th>Email</th><th>Username</th>";
            echo "<th>Password</th><th>Apagar</th></tr>";

            $i = 0;
             while($registos = mysqli_fetch_array($faz_procura,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                if($i & 1) {
                    echo '<tr bgcolor=yellow>';
                } else {
                   echo '<tr bgcolor=grey>';
                }
                echo '<td>'.$registos['Matricula'];
                echo '<td>'.$registos['User'];
                echo '<td>'.$registos['Marca'];
                echo '<td>'.$registos['Ano'];
                echo '<td>'.$registos['Celindrada'];
                echo '<td><a href="apaga_carro.php?nome='.$registos['Matricula'].'">Elimina</a>';
                echo '</td>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'matricula' Da este erro :/

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C(...)

Agora da esse erro

Comment: Já mudei. Agora deu o mesmo erro do inicio..

Comment: Ya ok. Era esse o problema.........
Tinha ideia que ser letra grande ou pequena não tinha importância.
Obrigado :)